# Native linking failed, duplicate symbol

Tags: ios, xcode6, visual-studio-debugging, iphone-6, ios9.2

When I tried to debug the iOS to the Simulator, This happens after I include the Xamarin.InAppPurchase-Unified components in Xamarin.I have these errors shown in the screenshots. How will I fix this one.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]om/nDRKs.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you project has two crach_report pb.c.m file?

Comment: How will i confirm if i have 2 file on that one?

Comment: usually dupicate sympile is have some .m file, your .m file is in a .a package?  so it is a little difficut  to find some .m file in .a pakeage  I am sorry i have no english resouce give to you  I am a china people

Comment: No. I don't have any idea how to find those duplicates. Can you show me the steps?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can ask for help to who offer you .a file ，They may Know how to solve it .fellow step give you thought may help you

## 1.look lipo -info libSBJSON.a

[image]
you will see has  armv7 arm64 construct

## 2.first separate  armv7  construct

Lipo -thin armv7 libSBJSON.a -output libSBJSON_armv7

[image]
the seperated armv7 pacgage place current dictionary

## 3. open  armv7 pacgage

Ar -t libSBJSON_armv7 | grep SBJson

[image]
when open pacgage ,you will see .o

## 4. delete the conflict  .o file

Ar -dv libSBJSON_armv7 SBJsonStreamParserState-4FEA9E115CD0E45C.o

[image]

## 5. repeat  2，3，4 use to arm64

## 6. after deletae the confict .o ,merge arm64  and armv7 package

Lipo -create libSBJSON_armv7 libSBJSON_arm64 -output libSBJSON.a

[image]

Comment: run on iphone has problem？